# An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'SubImgPath' that is not defined in this report?

Tags: c#, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have created a child report which loads data if a parameter is passed from Parent Report. It works fine except for the IMAGE. Image doesn't load. It fails by throwing error:

> An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'SubImgPath' that is not defined in this report.

I have defined a parameter 'SubImgPath' inside Child Report and sending parameter but fails:

```
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
    string FilePath = new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/")).AbsoluteUri;
    ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter("SubImgPath", FilePath);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the parameter in your report.

In the designer you can use this command: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to open the `Report Data` panel, or you can access it by the menu:  `View > Report Data`

Here you can define the parameters for your report.

Here is in short how to pass down a report parameter:

> - Goto `SubReport > Report Data Pane > Parameters` and add the    parameter you want to receive.
> - Goto `MainReport > Right-click SubReport > Subreport Properties >    Parameters` and add the same parameter name and pick the relevant
>   value from the dropdown.